# Is there a reason my Haskell program uses so much memory?

Tags: performance, haskell, memory, functional-programming, haskell-stack

Given an input file of words separated by spaces, file size ~64mb:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    content <- getData "data_1.txt" -- opens file, reads contents, closes handle,returns
    let tokens = words content
        mappedData = map (\token -> (token, 1)) tokens
        keySet = Set.fromList tokens
        intermediateData = map (\key -> (key, map snd (filter (\kv -> fst kv == key) mappedData))) (Set.toList keySet)
        final = map (\pair -> (fst pair, foldr (+) 0 (snd pair))) intermediateData
    print final
```

vs

```py
content = ""
with open("data_1.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()

tokens = content.split()

intermediate_data = []

for token in tokens:
    intermediate_data.append((token, 1))

keys = set()
for pair in intermediate_data:
    keys.add(pair[0])

grouped_values = []
for key in keys:
    values = [y for x, y in intermediate_data if x == key]
    grouped_values.append((key, values))

final = []
for elem in grouped_values:
    reduced = sum(elem[1])
    final.append((elem[0], reduced))

print(final)
```

The Haskell program uses 4.1 GB of RAM vs the Python program's 1.7 GB. They both do nearly the exact same thing, and while this example is 100% lazy evaluated, mostly strict evaluation basically doesn't improve usage at all. Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong?

I could parallelize the Haskell program or use some more efficient data structures, but there seems to be an underlying issue since the RAM usage is ~2.5x greater than Python. I imagine if I used a faster compiled language, the RAM usage would be even less.

Comment: Using `ByteString` will be more space efficient. It uses arrays of contiguous memory rather than `String`, which is a linked list.

Comment: The basic type `String` is known to be rather memory-inefficient for long strings. You could try using [`Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0.2/docs/Data-Text.html) instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. `String` is a linked list of characters. That's horrible in terms of memory footprint (≈128 bits per character, when 8 would be enough for English text). This type should only be used for strings that have either need to be processed lazily (specifically, character-by-character lazy), or are so few and short that efficiency doesn't matter (and you are confident that it won't be more during runtime in an unusual use case).
   If that's not the case, you should either use [`ByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html) (for exact encoding control and binary data), or [`Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0.2/docs/Data-Text.html) if using it as, well, *text* which seems to be the case here.
2. You're storing multiple lists of the words, in simple and annotated forms, *in addition* to the set of words. Because of the multiple uses, GHC probably won't be able to fuse them away, and at least one of the lists will be fully represented in memory instead of being incrementally garbage collected. Whether this actually matters depends on the length of the individual words: if these are long enough strings, then the actual character storage will dominate memory usage anyway.
3. Don't use `foldr (+)` for computing a sum. Use simply `sum`, which has better strictness built in to make this efficient. (Doesn't actually matter here.)
4. Your algorithm is super inefficient, looping over both all the words in order and the set of words. This is quite unnecessary, since the creation of a `Set` already involves merging equal words together. If you switch to the similar `Map`, you can tap into that merging for accumulating the counters, and thus never need to store all those redundant `1`-s.

Try this:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Map as M

main :: IO ()
main = do
    content <- T.readFile "data_1.txt"
    let tokens = T.words content
        mappedData = Map.fromListWith (+)
            $ map (\token -> (token, 1)) tokens
        final = Map.toList mappedData
    print final
```

... or shorter

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

main = do
    content <- T.readFile "data_1.txt"
    print . Map.toList . Map.fromListWith (+)
        $ (,1) <$> T.words content
```

Using [`readFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0.2/docs/Data-Text-IO.html#v:readFile) actually still makes this far from ideal, because that uses old `Char`s under the hood. In this case, the char-list *should* get fused away though / incrementally garbage collected, so that not all of them reside in memory simultaneously, only the resulting `Text` is.

You could take this even further, by not even reading in the complete text but only doing it lazily. That should make it a lot more memory-slim yet.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as TL
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as TL

main = do
    content <- TL.decodeUtf8 <$> BL.readFile "data_1.txt"
    print . Map.toList . Map.fromListWith (+)
        $ (,1) . TL.toStrict <$> TL.words content
```

In this version, the runtime would be able to garbage-collect the first words already before most of the others are ever read into memory, and only the duplicate-reduced form needs to be stored permanently.

But do note that lazy IO is fiddly, it's easy to accidentally e.g. close a file before you're really finished with it. If using this in a real application, you should ensure the list of results is fully evaluated / in memory before handing on control.

Comment: Would be interesting if you could measure how much memory these versions use.

Comment: So using my Haskell example in the original post and swapping String for Text, memory usage dropped in half to about exactly 2 GB. Using your optimized code, roughly 1-1.5 GB, although it spikes to about 2 GB when printing the output.

Comment: Using: `foldr (\word -> M.insertWith (+) word 1) M.empty T.words fileText` I reduced it down to 800 - 900 MB while running, and 1.3 GB while printing. I suspect this is due to 1 less map over all the data

Comment: Using: `foldl (\acc word -> HM.insertWith (+) word 1 acc) HM.empty $ T.words fileText` Using HashMap instead of Map and foldl over foldr, memory usage is ~350 MB, with no noticeable spike while printing!